# Efficient calculation of vector between sets of 3D points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm coding a particular version of raytracing in Python, and I'm trying to calculate the vectors between points on different planes.

I'm working with sets of point light sources, simulating a nonpoint light source. Each source generates one ray for each pixel on the "camera" plane. I managed to compute the vector for each of those rays, by iterating with a for loop for each pixel:

```py
for sensor_point in sensor_points:    
    sp_min_ro = sensor_point - rayorigins #Vectors between the points
    normalv = normalize(sp_min_ro) #Normalized vector between the points
```

Where `sensor_points` is a large numpy array with the [x,y,z] coordinates of the different pixel positions, and `rayorigins` is a numpy array with the [x,y,z] coordinates for the different point sources

This for loop approach works, but is extremely slow. I tried to remove the for loop and directly calculate `spr_min_ro = sensor_points - rayorigins`, with the whole array, but numpy can't operate it:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1002001,3) (36,3)`

Is there a way to accelerate the process of finding the vectors between all the points?

---

Edit: Adding the normalize function definition I have been using, because it is also giving problems:

```py
def normalize(v):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)
    return v / norm[:,None]
```

When I try to pass the new (1002001, 36, 3) array from @aganders3 solution, it fails, I suppose because of the axis?

Comment: Share implementation of `normalize`?

Comment: @Divakar Added the normalize function definition, which it is indeed giving me trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Numpy solution

```
import numpy as np

sensor_points=np.random.randn(1002001,3)#.astype(np.float32)
rayorigins=np.random.rand(36,3)#.astype(np.float32)

sp_min_ro = sensor_points[:, np.newaxis, :] - rayorigins
norm=np.linalg.norm(sp_min_ro,axis=2)
sp_min_ro/=norm[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

**Timings**

```
np.float64: 1.76 s ± 26.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
np.float32: 1.42 s ± 9.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Numba solution

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def normalized_vec(sensor_points,rayorigins):
    res=np.empty((sensor_points.shape[0],rayorigins.shape[0],3),dtype=sensor_points.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(sensor_points.shape[0]):
        for j in range(rayorigins.shape[0]):
            vec_x=sensor_points[i,0]-rayorigins[j,0]
            vec_y=sensor_points[i,1]-rayorigins[j,1]
            vec_z=sensor_points[i,2]-rayorigins[j,2]
            dist=np.sqrt(vec_x**2+vec_y**2+vec_z**2)
            res[i,j,0]=vec_x/dist
            res[i,j,1]=vec_y/dist
            res[i,j,2]=vec_z/dist
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit res=normalized_vec(sensor_points,rayorigins)
np.float64: 208 ms ± 4.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
np.float32: 104 ms ± 515 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

### Numba solution with preallocated memory

Memory allocation could be very costly. This example should show, why it is sometimes a good idea to avoid large temporary arrays if possible.

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def normalized_vec(sensor_points,rayorigins,res):
    for i in nb.prange(sensor_points.shape[0]):
        for j in range(rayorigins.shape[0]):
            vec_x=sensor_points[i,0]-rayorigins[j,0]
            vec_y=sensor_points[i,1]-rayorigins[j,1]
            vec_z=sensor_points[i,2]-rayorigins[j,2]
            dist=np.sqrt(vec_x**2+vec_y**2+vec_z**2)
            res[i,j,0]=vec_x/dist
            res[i,j,1]=vec_y/dist
            res[i,j,2]=vec_z/dist
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
res=np.empty((sensor_points.shape[0],rayorigins.shape[0],3),dtype=sensor_points.dtype)
%timeit res=normalized_vec(sensor_points,rayorigins)
np.float64: 66.6 ms ± 131 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
np.float32: 33.8 ms ± 375 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the rules for [NumPy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). I think adding a new axis in the middle of your `sensor_points` array will work:

```
>> sp_min_ro = sensor_points[:, np.newaxis, :] - rayorigins
>> sp_min_ro.shape
(1002001, 36, 3)
```

Comment: I'm having now problems with the normalize definition. I definitely have troubles reshaping (ha!) my head around the numpy arrays dimensions

Comment: What's the error it gives you? I think you want `norm = np.linalg.norm(v, axis=2)` in your normalize function, and I don't think you need the `[:, None]` in the division. This is pretty old though, haha - I don't really remember answering this.